# How to use the expression "с катушек"?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Интересно, слетит ли он **с катушек** еще раз?

I wonder if this is a set expression with the meaning of:

> I wonder if he will **go out of his mind** and fly away once again.

Comment: The corresponding English expression is "fly off the handle". There's nothing about "flying away" there, otherwise your translation is quite adequate.

Comment: I believe the image is taken from a process of lifting hewvy weights by industrial cranes, rolling some wires over the spindle wheels. If the wire started to unroll over the wheel side - then the weight would uncontrollsbly fly down, potentially breaking the crane and everything below

Answer (score 5):

**Слететь с катушек** is equal to "**go crazy /mad, to lose control, to behave inadequately**."

> Иван совсем с катушек слетел, ругается дебоширит.  Дай бог ему здоровья и не слететь с катушек.  Можно было сразу слететь с катушек, это был удар по нервной системе.

Answer (score 2):

"Слетит ли он с катушек" is translated as "if he will go out of his mind"
So, the correct translation will be "I wonder if he will go out of his mind once again".